Setting Up an Ideal Spring MVC Project with JPA, MySQL, and Tomcat (Java-Based Configuration)
I'm looking to set up an ideal Spring MVC project that utilizes the following technologies:

Java: 17 or 21

Spring: Spring MVC

JPA: For data persistence

Database: MySQL

Server: Tomcat 10/11

Project Structure: I would like to use DTOs for data transfer.


Additionally, I want to use Java-based configuration only, avoiding XML configurations.

I have a few questions regarding the setup:

Dependency Structure: What should the pom.xml file look like? Specifically, what dependencies do I need to include for Spring MVC, JPA, MySQL, and Tomcat?

Project Type: Should I create the project using Spring Initializr, or would it be better to set it up as a Maven web application project from scratch?

Best Practices: Are there any best practices or tips for structuring the project, such as package organization and configuration files?

Java Configuration: How should I configure the application to connect to MySQL using JPA with Java-based configuration?

Running the Application: What are the steps to run the application on Tomcat once it's set up?



I have tried implement to implement but face numerous errors like no origin found, no mapping found for GET/...xyz.jsp etc.

A tutorial would be the best place to start. This question is very broad as asked.

Best way is to use Spring Initializr to generate a starter app

Use this link to generate a starter app using Spring Initializr with your requirements.
Once you open the link you'll see a download button to download the starter project.
Once downloaded, unzip the project and open using your favourite IDE.
Configure the mysql url and credentials in the application.properties under src/main/resources
In the default package there will be a Java class under src/main/java/ annotated with @SpringBootApplication. Run this main class and your application will be up and running on 8080 port.

Note that spring boot uses Apache Tomcat by default.
For JSP based UI, use the YouTube link to tutorials for JSP + Spring Boot

As I am aware this technique is being used to setup the spring boot project and I want to make a Spring MVC project so I assume there should be a different approach to setup the Spring MVC project.

@Vivek, The above mentioned process is not just spring boot, you will be enabling Spring MVC when you add the spring web starter dependency to the project.
Same can be done without Springboot but the setup would be much more complicated than this.
This is the easiest way. Moreover, now a days Spring Boot has become standard.
I suggest you try it if you are new to Java/Spring.
